# Get Select Value and Option from Specific Table Row and Column with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, html-select

I have a table that has rows appended to it. Each row has a select in column 2 `{0, 1, [2]}`. I am trying to get the text/value/option of the select using JavaScript or JQuery. This seems like it should be something easy but for the life of me I cannot figure out a way to get the select element in the selected row & column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my table.

```
 <div id="table_container">
        <table id="computer_table" class="service_table">
            <thead id="header_container">
            <th class="table_header">COMPUTER NAME</th>
            <th class="table_header">LIVE/HIDE</th>
            <th class="table_header">MODE</th>
            <th class="table_header">RUN</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table_body">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript that adds rows to the table. Rows contain a select in column 2.

```
row = $('<tr class="row_white"><td class="tb_pc_name">' + value.pc_name + '</td><td class="tb_live_hide">LIVE</td><td class="tb_mode">' +
                        '<select id="select_mode" class="select_dropdown">' +
                        '<option value="0">0 - DEFAULT</option>' +
                        '<option value="1">1 - CLEAN UP</option>' +
                        '<option value="2">2 - SIGN IN</option>' +
                        '<option value="3">3 - SIGN OUT</option>' +
                        '<option value="4">4 - UPDATE IPSW</option>' +
                        '<option value="5">5 - OPEN DMG DIRECTORY</option>' +
                        '</select></td>' +
                        '<td class="tb_btn"><button type="button" id="btn_run">RUN</button></td></tr>');


                    $("#computer_table").append(row);
```

After all rows have been appended, the user can make a selection from the select. There is a button in column 3 that when clicked should show an alert with the select option and value of the select on the same row. The code below should show the selected option and/or value of the select in the row of the cell that is clicked. I can get the row and column but cannot get the value of the select.

```
 $("#computer_table td").click(function() {

                    var table = document.getElementById('computer_table');

                    var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );
                    var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() );

                    alert('test');

               /*Error here.*******************************************************************************************/
                    var combo = table.rows[row_num + 1].cells[2].getElementById('select_mode');
 //$("#select_mode option:contains("?").attr('selected', 'selected');
                    alert(combo.value);

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed your buttons to use a class rather than an id they could be triggered with this:

```
$("#computer_table").on("click", "button.btn_run", function(e) {
    alert($(this).parent().prev().children().find(":selected").text());
});
```

Comment: This does work but if you have multiple rows it will show an alert for every select in every row from the row that the button was clicked and each row > than that row.

Comment: Yes true enough. I've updated the answer to handle this. You would only need to call this event listener once and it would work for all buttons created in the future

Comment: It works great. Thanks for yours and everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is something wrong with youre code that add the row. Every ID must be unique and it's not the case. Try using a counter (or something else) to avoid that like this:

```
var numberRowAdded = 0;

row = $('<tr class="row_white"><td class="tb_pc_name">' + value.pc_name + '</td><td class="tb_live_hide">LIVE</td><td class="tb_mode">' +
                        '<select id="select_mode'+ numberRowAdded  +'" class="select_dropdown">' +
                        '<option value="0">0 - DEFAULT</option>' +
                        '<option value="1">1 - CLEAN UP</option>' +
                        '<option value="2">2 - SIGN IN</option>' +
                        '<option value="3">3 - SIGN OUT</option>' +
                        '<option value="4">4 - UPDATE IPSW</option>' +
                        '<option value="5">5 - OPEN DMG DIRECTORY</option>' +
                        '</select></td>' +
                        '<td class="tb_btn"><button type="button" id="btn_run'+ numberRowAdded  +'">RUN</button></td></tr>');


                    $("#computer_table").append(row);
numberRowAdded++;
```

Then to select what you want :

```
$("#computer_table td").click(function() {
    alert($(this).find(".select_dropdown").val());

});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Gotcha. I plan on giving each a unique id. (The computer Name). How can I apply this to the button so that when it is clicked it will display an alert with the select value on the same row? BTW Thanks for the above answer also. Helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

try passing in the ID onClick:

```
$("#computer_table td").click(function(this.id){    }
```

Just make sure all your cells have an ID.

Here is W3 example on enclosures and encapsulation.  This is useful for giving all your elements a different ID.  [W3 encapsulation example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_counter3)

**Adding elements with eventlisteners attached, and passing in a unique id!!**
*Note: this is not an exact fix for your code.  This should however aid you in understanding.

```
/*use this function to create unique id's*/
 var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();


/*grab your table*/
 var table =document.getElementById("computer_table"); 
 /* create an element, set it's attributes*/
 var newRow = document.createElement("th");
 newRow.setAttribute("class", "table_header");
 newRow.setAttribute("id", "table_header"+add());
/*add the event listener*/ 
 newRow.addEventListener("click",function(this.id){  /* YOUR CODE HERE */ });  
 /*append to your table*/
 table.appendChild(newRow);
```